# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable , problem with passing generated array to second iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I am trying to run 500 iterations in optimization problem. I am doing some changes on pop array and than I am trying to pass it again to the next iteration, however run into error, tho the first iteration is working all fine, I get pop array and then pass it to created_moved_pop and `create_star_pop` and get some problems. Will be very thankful if someone could explain my why this happens

error trace
C:\Users\yuliy\PycharmProjects\method_deform_stars\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/yuliy/PycharmProjects/method_deform_stars/DS.py
[0.8575697060274371, 0.8802225709314421, 0.6098937002728221, 0.5482650148523068, 0.5395302259903021, 0.6330576538506912, 0.734280095260012, 0.6826885236666879, 0.5797401283594749, 0.8381278588403586, 0.4983449567579089, 0.37081148554598065, 0.19916270916904044, 0.7590390380364216, 0.8272752130297748, 0.8837021413140848, 0.9750382019031415, 0.5436068899712437, 0.6490739970397773, 0.3014768191053475]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yuliy/PycharmProjects/method_deform_stars/DS.py", line 70, in 
    star_pop = create_star_pop(pop)
[(0.11503376215798591, 6.794025806650792), (0.5133530350808552, 1.0230252795290697), (0.37081148554598065, 0.8887201815324006), (0.4201038734097051, 0.8215339609930865), (0.6098937002728221, 0.7952234761836543), (0.19916270916904044, 0.7689552603259296), (0.250319764137194, 0.7111682294644993), (0.3014768191053475, 0.7008819653567403), (0.6582300480283956, 0.6632231712798371), (0.6666685334677784, 0.658688271415733), (0.7646482839856097, 0.6322183223530311), (0.8120560994714594, 0.6155315414048562), (0.7590390380364216, 0.59962403681057), (0.8609150000772217, 0.569512653796447), (0.8083043720319294, 0.5354111445749077), (0.620024614496207, 0.4887918787850577), (0.5035114962372264, 0.4844464118877576), (0.8670977366853939, 0.48321853250106644), (0.5541193285153655, 0.4821747663938167), (0.8575697060274371, 0.47491541406252397)]
  File "C:/Users/yuliy/PycharmProjects/method_deform_stars/DS.py", line 60, in create_star_pop
    new_element = star_pop(population)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
[0.11503376215798591, 0.5133530350808552, 0.37081148554598065, 0.4201038734097051, 0.6098937002728221, 0.19916270916904044, 0.250319764137194, 0.3014768191053475, 0.6582300480283956, 0.6666685334677784, 0.7646482839856097, 0.8120560994714594, 0.7590390380364216, 0.8609150000772217, 0.8083043720319294, 0.620024614496207, 0.5035114962372264, 0.8670977366853939, 0.5541193285153655, 0.8575697060274371]

Process finished with exit code 1

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import operator

# Global variables
a = 0.1
b = 1


def function(x):
    return (math.sin(40*math.pi*x)+math.pow(x-1, 4))/(2*x)


def initial_pop():
    pop = np.random.uniform(a, b, 20)
    pop = pop.tolist()
    return pop


def moving_pop(population):
    # e c
    rand_item = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    # print(rand_item)
    direction_arr = [-1, 1]
    direction = direction_arr[random.randrange(len(direction_arr))]
    # print(direction)
    new_element = rand_item + direction * np.random.normal(0, 0.2)
    if new_element > b:
        extra = new_element - b
        new_element = a + extra
    if new_element < a:
        extra = abs(new_element - a)
        new_element = b - extra
    # print(new_element)
    return new_element


def create_moved_pop(population):
    new_population = []
    for x in range(0, 20):
        new_element = moving_pop(population)
        new_population.append(new_element)
    # print(new_population)
    return new_population


def star_pop(population):
    random_item1 = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    random_item2 = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    while random_item2 == random_item1:
        random_item2 = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    e_star = (random_item1 + random_item2)/2
    return e_star


def create_star_pop(population):
    star_population = []
    for x in range(0, 20):
        new_element = star_pop(population)
        star_population.append(new_element)
    # print(new_population)
    return star_population


pop = initial_pop()
print(pop)
for i in range(0, 500):
    moved_pop = create_moved_pop(pop)
    star_pop = create_star_pop(pop)
    pop_combined = sorted(sorted(pop) + sorted(moved_pop) +                 
sorted(star_pop))
    y_array = []
    for x in range(0, len(pop_combined)):
        y_array.append(function(pop_combined[x]))
    x_y_array = dict(zip(pop_combined, y_array))

    sorted_x_y_array = sorted(x_y_array.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    sorted_x_y_array = sorted_x_y_array[0:20]
    print(sorted_x_y_array)
    pop.clear()
    for x in sorted_x_y_array:
        pop.append(x[0])
    print(pop)
```

Comment: Please add to your question *the full error message you receive including the stack trace*. That saves having to scan through the code trying to work out what line might be causing the error message. And that in turn is likelier to get you a helpful response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are re-defining star_pop as list

```
star_pop = create_star_pop(pop)
```

find the below fixed code

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import operator

# Global variables
a = 0.1
b = 1


def function(x):
    return (math.sin(40*math.pi*x)+math.pow(x-1, 4))/(2*x)


def initial_pop():
    pop = np.random.uniform(a, b, 20)
    pop = pop.tolist()
    return pop


def moving_pop(population):
    # e c
    rand_item = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    # print(rand_item)
    direction_arr = [-1, 1]
    direction = direction_arr[random.randrange(len(direction_arr))]
    # print(direction)
    new_element = rand_item + direction * np.random.normal(0, 0.2)
    if new_element > b:
        extra = new_element - b
        new_element = a + extra
    if new_element < a:
        extra = abs(new_element - a)
        new_element = b - extra
    # print(new_element)
    return new_element


def create_moved_pop(population):
    new_population = []
    for x in range(0, 20):
        new_element = moving_pop(population)
        new_population.append(new_element)
    # print(new_population)
    return new_population


def star_pop(population):
    random_item1 = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    random_item2 = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    while random_item2 == random_item1:
        random_item2 = population[random.randrange(len(population))]
    e_star = (random_item1 + random_item2)/2
    return e_star


def create_star_pop(population):
    star_population = []
    for x in range(0, 20):
        new_element = star_pop(population)
        star_population.append(new_element)
    # print(new_population)
    return star_population


pop = initial_pop()
print(pop)
for i in range(0, 500):
    moved_pop = create_moved_pop(pop)
    star_pop_ = create_star_pop(pop)
    pop_combined = sorted(sorted(pop) + sorted(moved_pop) +                 
sorted(star_pop_))
    y_array = []
    for x in range(0, len(pop_combined)):
        y_array.append(function(pop_combined[x]))
    x_y_array = dict(zip(pop_combined, y_array))

    sorted_x_y_array = sorted(x_y_array.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    sorted_x_y_array = sorted_x_y_array[0:20]
    print(sorted_x_y_array)
    pop.clear()
    for x in sorted_x_y_array:
        pop.append(x[0])
    print(pop)
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't give the error now, however each iteration should create different values and i get same values from second iteration and so on

Answer (score 0):

You got a method called star_pop and an object called star_pop, in the 2nd iteration of the for loop you are trying

```
    new_element = star_pop(population)
```

after doing

```
star_pop = create_star_pop(pop)
```

which returns a list

I think you mixed up your names. You can fix it by renaming either the function or the star_pop list.

Unrelated to that, you dont need to include the 0 in range(0, 500). Ranges always start at 0 by default.